# How to use a wild card query for both field and value in Lucene?

Tags: java, solr, lucene

My problem is how to parse wildcard queries with Lucene for both field and value.

I'm storing a jsonObject as a canonical path in the lucene document. Example :

```
"field1":{
    "field2":{
       "field3":"test"}
     }
  }
```

It is stored as

```
field1.field2.field3 : test
```

I'm using `QueryParser` with `keywordAnalyser`. My problem is that I want to use wildcard in field also.It is working fine for field's value. Example :

`field1.field2.field3 : tes*`   is working fine but I want to use something like this `field1.*.field3: tes*` .

How can I achieve this?

Note: As an input I receive a query string, so building queries programmatically is not an option. Note: I'm using Lucene 8.11.2.

I cannot store * for field2 in the generated lucene document.